# Как загрузить файлы на сервера телеграм для чат бота с локальной машины

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Есть задача получить из файла на локальной машине file_id для отправки ботом. Как это можно сделать не отправляя файл с помощью самого бота ?

Пробовал получать их через Telethon, но для чат ботов и юзер ботов используются разные айди